# How to convert a conventional piano or a violin score to the guitar tabulature using Musescore, Finale, Tuxguitar, Sibelius, Guitarpro softwares?

Tags: guitar, software, tablature, transcription

How to convert a conventional piano or a violin score to the guitar tabulature using Musescore, Finale, Tuxguitar, Sibelius, GuitarPro softwares? Is it possible and how it will handle multiple note positions on the guitar fretboard?

Comment: What is your goal? You can imagine that there are piano scores that are not playable on a guitar.

Comment: Need a an automatic assistance to produce a guitar tab, not to do it manually, just to edit the result, surely, not all scores are directly convertable, but many passages and lines and chords are convertable

Comment: I don't know every app that you listed, but in the ones I do know, just create "guitar notation" and "guitar tab" staves and copy-and-paste the music. There is often a "set-up" or "options" page to control the tab notation, define the guitar tuning, etc. Just download some free demos, read the help files, and follow your nose.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general guide for Sibelius: Enter the score either manually or by scanning. Now create new instrument (guitar). You may need to create two guitar parts. Copy and paste the piano/violin stave/s into the guitar stave/s. Edit the parts. Then go to Plug Ins and select Guitar Tab. You will get to choose the highest fret the tab will use. Allow yourself plenty of time, because you will need to deal with stems, voices, and notes out of range. Muse Score? Bless its clunky little head. Someone will have nutted out how to do it, but it's probably best to start by climbing Mt Everest, nude, backwards, carrying a honey badger and setting off from Antarctica. Ok, my experience with MuseScore was limited, and nearly a decade ago, but I've not been the same since.